# Apps for practicing math (all levels)

Tags: applications

I am looking for an app that I can use to PROVIDE me with math problems for practice and to stay fresh on various subjects in mathematics. This includes all levels of math (from low grade school to differential equations, linear algebra, ect). These practice problems would be random and new each time so that they continue to challenge me and provide an endless supply of practice.

That is the ideal, if this is not realistic I would settle for a handful of apps that provide most (if not all) of the subjects for practice examples. I am finding many options for subjects up to basic grade school math and one that goes up to precalculus but I would like to practice the upper level problems as well.

Note: What I mean by "provide me with problems" is if I were to "generate" a problem for a particular subset of mathematics I would be presented with an appropriate problem that I would be able to solve and put in an answer to be given feedback for. This app does not need to provide a calculator or any math solving tools/software.

Thank you.

Comment: Why an app? Why not a website like brilliant.org?

Comment: @AspiringMat Never heard of brilliant.org but just checked the site out and that seems fantastic! An app would be prefered due to the convenience, both a website and an app would be great also. I noticed brilliant.org has an app and its already downloading. Thank you! Any other good considerations?

Answer (score 1):

Here some possibilities:

1. Visual Math: KickBox and KickBox Lite
   KickBox, a math game created by MIND Research Institute and inspired by its penguin Jiji®, helps students learn key math concepts visually. Students use mirrors to position lasers to knock the boulders out of the way for the penguin. This app is a great tool to reinforce multistep thinking.
2. Numbers: Elevated Math
   This free app, created by Elevated Math Press, walks students through basic math problems to learn numbers, algebra, measurements, geometry and more. The lessons bundled in this app are recommended for grades four to eight. According to the site, this app can be used for SAT and ACT studying.
3. Numbers: Motion Math Zoom
   Motion Math Zoom, a free app for elementary students, helps kids learn numbers and decimals with a fun and engaging game.
4. Geometry: iCrosss
   iCrosss, priced at $0.99, is complex app that helps students dive into geometry concepts with 3D drawings and descriptions of shapes. In the app, students can easily rotate the drawings and diagrams to get a concrete grasp of the shapes.
5. Algebra: HMH Fuse: Algebra 1
   Created by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt (HMH, this app brings an Algebra 1 textbook to life with interactive graphs, tools and equations! What’s more, it includes 400 tutorial videos, step-by-step examples, quizzes and more to engage students in math learning. Yet the best part about it is that it’s – free.
6. Algebra: Algebra Pro – Complete Workbook with ShowMe Lessons
   Developed from the popular ShowMe app among teachers, this free app includes an interactive workbook with 100 practice questions that include ShowMe support videos.Calculus: Video Calculus
   Similar to the Khan Academy videos, this app gives you more than 2 hours worth of free calculus instruction through its visual videos. It also includes 15 free featured lessons.
7. Probability & Statistics: Statistics 1 for iPad
   This statistics app, priced at $4.99, provides students with interactive tutorials, lessons and quizes to learn statistics. It’s like having a statistics textbook in your pocket – only better.
8. Applying Math: Rocket Math
   In this app, students complete math problems in order to build their own rockets. Once they build their rockets, they’re able to explore space with 56 math missions. It’s recommended for all ages and costs just $0.99.
9. Applying Math: SpaceTime for iPad or MathStudio
   This is one powerful app for just $2.99. Students can create 2D and 3D diagrams using a graphic calculator. It’s definitely worth checking out.
10. Math Game: MathBlaster HyperBlast
    We’re big fans of fun learning. Created for ages six and over, this game looks like something out of an arcade. It’s brightly colored, fast-paced and engaging. This free app includes three game levels and 30 math lessons.

Answer (score 0):

My top picks:

Mathcounts trainer: It gives you lots and lots of problems from MATHCOUNTS middle-school competition, and it lets you draw in the app, so you can write your work down their without going through lots of pencils and papers.

Alcumus: This isn't really an app, but its a website you can access on mobile so what's the difference? It gives you problems more difficult than the ones in MATHCOUNTS. I believe that it covers problems in Prealgebra, Algebra, Number Theory, Counting/Probability, Geometry, Intermediate Algebra, and Precalculus. It also lets you pick a difficulty as well.
You can access it here https://artofproblemsolving.com/alcumus.

You can also find many other resources here https://artofproblemsolving.com/resources.